# How to add Magnific Popup manually in bower file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I have a rails application and I want to use Magnific Popup library in it.

The link **https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup** says you can install it via Bower **bower install magnific-popup** but this will install it only on my machine whereas I want to make it accessible on different machines as well.

So I want to add this library in Bower file manually. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bower i -S magnific-popup`